# Webpack bundle throwing Uncaught Type error

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to bundle my under development react app with webpack, however the generated bundle is throwing an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '.js' of undefined
```

Code where this error is thrown is

```
function hookExtensions(_exts) {
      /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _each2.default)(oldHandlers, function (old, ext) {
        if (old === undefined) {
          delete (void 0)[ext];
        } else {
          (void 0)[ext] = old;
        }
      });

      oldHandlers = {};

      /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _each2.default)(_exts, function (ext) {
        oldHandlers[ext] = (void 0)[ext];//error is thrown on this line
        registerExtension(ext);
      });
    }
```

My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

console.log(__dirname);

let config = {
  target:'electron-renderer',
  entry:'./app/Initializer',
  output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'appbundle.js',
    publicPath:'/dist/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions:["",".js",".jsx",".json"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders:[{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

What could I be doing wrong? Any help in this is appreciated.

Comment: What's `(void 0)` supposed to return, if not undefined/null?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I am getting the exact same thing with `ignore-styles.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '.css' of undefined` with ignore-styles `oldHandlers[ext] = (void 0)[ext];
    (void 0)[ext] = handler;`

Comment: Yes. I haven't been able to fix this. Since my software is not yet out, I am doing without using webpack right now. But I will have to get back to this soon. Please do let me know if you find a solution to this.